# Copy/Paste functionality not working

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to have Copy/Paste functionality in Activities screen.I am not able to get the drop down to the clipboard where it shows options for copy and paste.

[image]

```
public class CRActivityMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.EP.CRActivityMaint>
{
    public PXCopyPasteAction<CRActivity> CopyPaste;
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
       CopyPaste.SetVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Not all screens allow for copy and paste. Are you trying to customize the page to add Copy/Paste? (assuming this is an existing page). More details should be provided in the question to better assist.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to Customize the page to add Copy/Paste. I have edited the question providing the code

Comment: The Clipboard icon gets added but the drop down for copy and paste options  is not avaliable.

Comment: I was able to get the button to look correct by overriding CanClipboardCopyPaste, however the actual values never paste to another activity.   
[PXOverride]
    public virtual bool CanClipboardCopyPaste(Func<bool> del)
    {
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the copy and paste working within the Activity pop up page using the following:

```
public class CRActivityMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.EP.CRActivityMaint>
{
    public PXCopyPasteAction<CRActivity> CopyPaste;

    [PXOverride]
    public virtual bool CanClipboardCopyPaste(Func<bool> del)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is the copy data appears to be lost after the pop up page is closed. This I am not able to resolve. Maybe a template might be what you are looking for so I at least wanted to post as an answer vs a comment for the example as far as I was able to get.